# Phase shift of shifted impulse response

Tags: signal-processing, phase-shift, frequency-response

I have the following frequency response: 
$$H(e^{jkw_0}) = \begin{cases}0, & -4\leq k \leq-3\\ 1, &-2 \leq k \leq 2\\ 0, & 3\leq k \leq 4\end{cases}$$

And I have graphed \$h[n]4\$ as the following:
[image]

and \$h[n-4]\$ as the following:
[image]
I would like to argue that \$H_c (e^{jw}) = e^{-4jw}H(e^{jw}) \$ have the same magnitude about a strong phase shift. Would it be sufficient to say that the have the same magnitude based on "inspection?" And, for the phase shift, I can once again clearly see that it has time shifted by \$ 4 \$. However I am not sure how would I prove that the phase shift is \$ 4w\$.

Comment: Phase shift and time shift are not the same thing. That impulse shows a time shift of 4 samples. Phase shift is f(w). A pure time shift equates to f(w) being linear in w.

Comment: @Neil_UK The questioner is right. His phase shift formula is okay It contains the frequency. There's no problem in formulas, Only his understanding on them falters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A time delay T is represented in frequency domain as a multiplicator. That multiplicator is exp(-2*Pi * f * T *j). You have 4 unit interval delay, so your formula is right. But its interpretation falters.

The complex exponential multiplicator is only phase shift, no affect to amplitude. The phase lag (=negative phase shift) caused by that delay is not constant, but increases linearly as the freguency increases. At frequency 1/T the phase lag is full 2*Pi. You see that easily: A sine voltage with period=T is delayed exactly one period. It means phase lag = 2*Pi (or phase shift -2*Pi). Higher frequencies lag more and lower frequencies less.

Actually your expression 4W is ok for the phase lag, if W=2* Pi *f. Frequency f must be given in proportion to the sampling frequency. In the beginning you used frequency indexes k= -10....10, so to be notationally consistent, we must write in this formula f=k/10.

Comment: I don't understand why the phase lag is increasing linearyly as the frequency increases. Can this be explained further?

Comment: So my understanding is the following. If I were to take the absolute value of the shifted transfer function and the original, they would be the same b/c the amp of the exponential would just become 1. However, the phase shift is affected by the exponential multiplicator and the phase angle is derived by extracting the coefficient in front of $j$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Christian That's right. But maybe it's good to go back in time a little, say 120 years. Then sinusoidal signals were produced by rotating engines (as tody at least in terms of the total energy) Think a simple generator that produces one sinusoidal cycle per one full 360 degrees revolution. Let it rotate 50 revolutions/second (= 50Hz AC output). One revolution takes 20ms. Let's delay the output signal by some ultra long wire 1 ms. In that time the generator rotates 360 degrees/20 = 18 degrees. 1 ms delay  causes 18 degrees phase lag. Double the freq. Then 1 ms delay causes double lag. Got it?